# Illegal Instruction loading OpenSSL on 32-bit Android

Tags: android, delphi, openssl, indy

Using Delphi 11 and Indy 10, I am getting an error loading the OpenSSL libraries under Android32 on a Lenovo TB-X304F tablet running Android 8.1.0:

> Project XXX raised exception class Illegal instruction (4).

There are other similar posts on StackOverflow, but none that offers a solution.

I don't get this error under Android64 on the same device. Nor, do I get the error on an Android 11 device running Android32 or Android64. All the devices I'm testing can run Android64, so I'm not sure how important this error is. But, if I am required to submit both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of my app to the Play Store, it seems likely both versions should run.

I am using OpenSSL 1.0.2g (I get the same error using OpenSSL 1.0.0).

I use `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` to let Indy know where the libraries are located.

In the debugger, the error appears to occur when I attempt to step over the initial begin of the function `LoadSSLCryptoLibrary()` in unit `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders`.

Is there a work-around? Or, if this error is related to the version of the library, is there a version of OpenSSL eligible for the Play Store and more likely to run on the Lenovo with Android 8.1?

Comment: Where are you getting the OpenSSL binaries?  Are you build it yourself?

Comment: @AndrewHenle downloaded from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries

Comment: Using OpenSSL on Android 6 onward is ... tricky ... since Google dropped support for OpenSSL in favor of BoringSSL.